# Capture answer to "App would like to send you push notifications" alert

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The first time you call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` on your `UIApplication` object, `a UIAlertView` pops up saying "[app] would like to send you push notifications".

Is there any way to know when "OK" or "Don't allow" is tapped in this `AlertView`?

Currently `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called on my `AppDelegate`, even before a user makes a decision.

The reason I ask is because on first launch, I want to push a `ViewController` with `Notification` options, but only if the user indicated that they want to receive notifications.

Answer (score 3):

You can use next method of `UIApplication`:

*Returns the types of notifications the application accepts.*

```
- (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes
```

For example,

```
UIRemoteNotificationType status = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (status == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
{
     NSLog(@"user is not subscribed to receive push notifications");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the problem I'm having is that `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called even before you tap "Don't allow" or "OK" in the AlertView.
So, at this moment `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is always `UIRemoteNotificationNone`.
I think I'd have to call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` again when that selection is made.