# Can an app receive a token from a push server even if the user has declined the app to receive push notifications?

Tags: ios

If when an app launches and registers with the Apple servers the user selects Don't Allow when the app/os displays the dialog to inform the user that the app wishes to send push notifications, then does the registration process still proceed but the app never receives any notifications, or is the registration process aborted at that point?

In other words, could an app still register and receive a token from the push notification servers even if the user has declined, but it can't actually be used for anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  The callback "application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" will not be called if the user does not approve the dialog and that's the only way to retrieve the token.

Comment: Thanks. What do you make of this posting, where the OP claims didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called before the user taps Don't Allow/OK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672090/capture-answer-to-app-would-like-to-send-you-push-notifications-alert

Comment: application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is in fact called BEFORE the user has approved notifications. At least in iOS 5.